# FB Like Box not showing stream for facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-likebox

I cannot get my FB Like Box to show the facebook page stream.

My facebook page url is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bellal%C3%A1ser-M%C3%A9xico/587970527913015  and when I goes to check in like box at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ but it not showing facebook page stream. any one can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your page or the individual posts on it restricted in any way?

Comment: My all page feeds are not showing...